# How to Get in between button tag text value in IFormCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a search form on view that displays check boxes as a list which may be selected multi, on each item check, value comes in between button tags.

In Controller Action IFormCollection provides various key value but not that button which tags contain results, it always returns null

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" name="State" data-placeholder="---" class="dropdown-toggle js-select-checkboxes-btn">---</button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu js-dropdown-menu js-select-checkboxes">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input id="checkbox_type_1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_type_1" class="in-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_type_1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on top" class="in-label">Punjab</label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input id="checkbox_type_2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_type_2" class="in-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_type_2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top" class="in-label">Sindh</label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input id="checkbox_type_3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_type_3" class="in-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_type_3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top" class="in-label">Balochistan</label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input id="checkbox_type_4" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_type_4" class="in-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_type_4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top" class="in-label">Khaybar Pakhtonkhwa</label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input id="checkbox_type_5" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_type_5" class="in-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_type_5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top" class="in-label">Azad Kashmir</label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input id="checkbox_type_6" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_type_6" class="in-checkbox">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_type_6" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top" class="in-label">Gilgit Baltistan</label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <!-- end of block .dropdown-menu-->
                                        </div>
```

In Page Source:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-placeholder="---" class="dropdown-toggle js-select-checkboxes-btn" aria-expanded="true">Punjab, Sindh, Balochistan</button>
```

In Controller Action Result:

```
public IActionResult SearchPerson(IFormCollection formCollection)
    {
        string txtState = formCollection["State"]; << Null}
```

I Expect the output as string i.e. in between tags

Comment: You are using a non-standard dropdown menu there, so you should check out how to make it provide the values properly when submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found with a little Trick i.e.

Step 1. Created a hidden type input

```
<input type="hidden" id="State" name="State" placeholder=""   class="form-control">
```

Step 2. Create a javascript/jquery function to set hidden input value equals button tags inner html

```
function onsubmitclick() {
    var x = document.getElementById('btnState').innerHTML;    
    alert(x);
    $('#State').val(x);
};
```

Step 3. Call function at submit button i.e. will fire before moving to controller action.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="onsubmitclick()" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SearchPerson" class="form__submit" >Search</button>
```

Step 4. Accessed hidden input value at controller from IFormCollection.

```
public IActionResult SearchPerson(IFormCollection formCollection){string txtState = formCollection["State"];}
```

Done!

Comment: A little late..Yes hidden type does the tirck.

Answer (score 0):

You could not get the text value of `<button>` in `IFormCollection`.

For a workaround, you could add a hidden input in the form and pass the selected values to it when you click.Then you could get the value of the input in `IFormCollection` when you submit.

```
<input type="hidden" id="States" name="States" />
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-placeholder="---" class="dropdown-toggle js-select-checkboxes-btn" aria-expanded="true">---</button>
```

JS code:

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var line = "";
                $(".dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        line += $("+ label", this).text() + ",";
                    }
                });
                $("#States").val(line);
                $("button.dropdown-toggle").text(line);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SearchPerson(IFormCollection formCollection)
{
   string txtState = formCollection["States"];
```